# Can I downgrade from rails 5 to rails 4.2.5 on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, vps

Ok this may sound stupid, but I was setting up a VPS to deploy an rails app to... the app is built with rails 4.2.5.

On the server I accidentally installed rails -v 5.  And after deploying the app to the server I always get this error: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.` when I try to visit the site.

Since this is a Rails error I figured that it is due to the mismatched versions of (rails 4.2.5) at my computer and (rails 5) on the server side.

So my question is if it's possible to uninstall rails 5 and install 4.2.5 instead on the VPS server?

**EDIT**
Rails 5 was installed `gem install rails`and then `rbenv rehash`

Because I'm new to this all and the learning curve is steep I feel safer asking here instead of messing it up by my self :)

Comment: How did you installed Rails 5?

Comment: I installed it with `gem install rails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you installed rails using `gem install rails`, you can run `gem uninstall rails`and then `gem install rails -v 4.2.5`.

I recommend you to use a Gemfile. In it you can specify the version of the gems that you want to use and `bundle install` will handle the installation.

Comment: Thank you I'll check this out tomorrow